# custom font in android by using typeface

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

i want to customize font style, so following is my code

```
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Modernism-Disco.ttf");
                    date.setTypeface(font);
                    date.setText("my Name");
```

this shows the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
            at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
            at com.centricsol.org.awesomtorch.MainActivity$10.run(MainActivity.java:577)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my android studio doesn't show assets directory but it actually exists

[image]

Comment: Not seeing any issue but create a folder named fonts in assets folder and move your ttf to that folder and change the code to this
Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Modernism-Disco.ttf");

Comment: One of the most popular third party libs to customise fonts on Android si Calligraphy. Check it out: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: getContext().getResources().getAssets()

Answer (score 3):

As per your second picture you got `assets` folder inside `res` folder. This is incorrect location and you need to move your `assets` one level up to make it work:

```
assets/
java/
res/
AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your assets folder to your project directory so that res and assets folders are in same directory.

Comment: LOL for artificially bumped reputation for this "answer". Friend to OP, right?

Answer (score -2):

There are basically 4 things that can cause this:

1)You use the wrong extension

2)You placed the fonts in the assets folder and not inside assets/fonts/

3)You misspelled the fonts

4)The fonts need to be lowercase (in your case the solution is to rename Modernism-Disco.ttf to modernism-disco.ttf, strange)

Comment: I have used fonts directly in assets folder and also had its name in both lower and upper case and have worked with ttf and otf fonts. Except 3rd, I'm contradicting your answer.

Comment: there is chance if somebody do mistake any of the following. am not saying all the points are not exactly correct @HarishSridharan

Comment: Too generic answer and also not exactly correct. Points 1, 2 and 4 are not valid.